# Filter list of functions with list of booleans using Scalaz

Tags: scala, scalaz

Lets say i have a list with some functions and a list with boolean values, which acts like a configuration list, and sizes are equal.

```
val conf = List(true, false, true)
val funcs = List(f1, f2, f3)
```

And by merging them, the result should looks like this:

```
val res = List(f1, f3)
```

I'm pretty sure that this can be done with Applicative builder in Scalaz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I must note, that solving it without Scalaz is pretty straight forward:

```
scala> val a = List(true, false, true)
a: List[Boolean] = List(true, false, true)

scala> val b = List(1,2,3)
b: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> a.view.zip(b).filter(_._1).map(_._2).force
res3: Seq[Int] = List(1, 3)
```

Comment: `(a,b).zipped.collect{case (a,b) if a => b }` looks much nicer imo.

Comment: @sschaef I disagree. In my code it's just a flat flow of method applications, each performing just a single primitive operation, which is not the case in yours. Also it has an `O(n)` complexity while yours has `O(n^2)`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I agree with @sschaef in that his snippet **looks** nicer. The "flatness" you mention can be an interesting property in general, but I doubt that it is very relevant here (please elaborate of you disagree). The runtime complexity, on the other hand, is/can be very important - but this aspect is usually still independent from the way code looks.

Comment: Zipped returns an optimized collection, thus its values are not calculated until they are needed => `O(n)`

Comment: `(a,b).zipped.flatMap{case (a,b) => a.option(b)}` - just cause I'm biased against collect (`option` comes from `scalaz.syntax.std.boolean`)